# I want to dispaly internal and external memory seperately instead of mobile name directly on my computer

Tags: samsung

I have Samsung grand mobile. When I connect it to my computer, it displays the mobile name.
When I click on the name, it displays internal and external memory.

But I want my computer to directly display internal and external memory, not mobile name.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. Can you add some more details or perhaps attach a screenshot of the problem?

Comment: Okay I understood the question and I think that is impossible as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

The internal & external memory won't show normally because their is a hierarchy that is being followed. When you click on My Computer, it shows every device attached to the PC. In order for you to see just one device, you would click on which device you wanted, then continuing till you get to your location.

So the only possible solution to show them first would be to create a shortcut on your desktop, that you would use when your phone is plugged into the PC. Clicking the shortcut when your device isn't plugged in will return a invalid reference error.